# Does NTFS use B-Tree, B+Tree or both?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

I'm looking for information if NTFS uses B-Tree or B+Tree or both

This source states that: "Directories in NTFS are stored in B+trees that keep their entries sorted in alphabetic order. Along with the name of a file, NTFS directories also store the file reference number (i-node number) of the file, the size of the file, and the last modification time." [1](https://web.archive.org/web/20170213221835/http://www.nobius.org/%7Edbg/practical-file-system-design.pdf)

This source states that: "An NTFS index sorts attributes into a tree, specifically a B-tree." [2](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.48.1/indexes.html)

I'm looking for a detailed explanation how exactly NTFS implements B-tree, B+tree or both. I'm especially interested in graphs or diagrams that illustrate the implementation.